# rails: jbuilder returns an array of 1 json instead of a json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have the following simple jbuilder template

```
# temp.jbuilder
json.home_id                    command[:home_id]
json.query                      command[:query]
json.query_param                command[:query_param]
```

When I `x = render "temp", format: :json, locals: { command: { home_id: 0, query: "QQQ", query_param: "P" } }`

I always get an array in x, instead of getting a json object. Can you tell me why? is it the expected response?

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo in the question, but you have misspelled `locals` as `loacls`

Comment: @Marcus, sorry - I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [render_to_string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) instead of `render`:

> If you want to see the exact results of a call to render without needing to inspect it in a browser, you can call render_to_string. This method takes exactly the same options as render, but it returns a string instead of sending a response back to the browser.